# Como creo varios proyectos dentro de uno?

Tags: spring-boot, maven

Tengo un proyecto con un servidor Rest y una app de escritorio quiero meterlo todo en uno para subirlo junto a github.
He estado investiganmdo y he llegado a crear esto. Pero las clases que creo en el proyecto Servicio  no son validas es como si fuera texto plano no tiene import ni nada.
Pon padre

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.arquitectura.java</groupId>
<artifactId>PomPadre</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Proyecto</name>
<description>Proyecto fin de ciclo actualizado</description>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
    <module>Servidor</module>
</modules>
```

Pon hijo

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.arquitectura.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>PomPadre</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>Servidor</artifactId>
    <name>Servidor</name>
    <description>Servidor Rest</description>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.6</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Además no me deja meter dependecias en el pom hijo

Si veis la clase no tiene import de nada de lo quye he escrito y ademas  el icono de la clase la J esta hueca no es como los otros iconos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No me reconoce las clases Java para poder echarlo andar y el pon da esos errores

Answer (score 1):

En los proyectos maven multimodulo de deben declarar que hijos tiene el padre y el tipo de artefacto que se genera.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.arquitectura.java</groupId>
  <artifactId>PomPadre</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Proyecto</name>
  <description>Proyecto fin de ciclo actualizado</description>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <modules>
    <module>proyecto-hijo</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

Esa referencia al proyecto hijo es el nombre del proyecto

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.arquitectura.java</groupId>
    <artifactId>PomPadre</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>proyecto-hijo</artifactId>
<name>Servidor hijo</name>
<description>Servidor Rest</description>
</project>
```

Como veras en el hijo no hay necesidad de ponr valores que se pueden inferir del padre como el `groupId`.

### Y que pasa si es un proyecto basado en spring boot?

Si tu proyecto original tenia de por si un

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</parent>
```

En ese caso al borrarlo no tendra las versiones de las dependencias que heredaba del padre, para ello se me ocurren dos soluciones.

La primera es abrir ese pom padre `spring-boot-starter-parent` en tu repositorio maven local y Si tu MAVEN_HOME apunta  a tu carpeta .m2, para el ejemplo dado lo hallarias en

```
MAVEN_HOME/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.4.0.pom.xml
```

perderias todas las ventajas de un proyecto hijo del spring-boot starter, aunque es debatible si un proyecto grande y maduro deberia de seguir con las versiones por defecto o hacer la administracion de versiones por cuenta propia.

El segundo metodo que se me ocurre es tan simple que no se si este bien hecho y seria simplemente al pom padre agregarle a spring-boot-starter-parent como su padre.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.arquitectura.java</groupId>
  <artifactId>PomPadre</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Proyecto</name>
  <description>Proyecto fin de ciclo actualizado</description>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  <modules>
    <module>proyecto-hijo</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

Comment: Si y no . Tras modificarlo lo acepta pero sigue sin dejarme meter librerias modico la preguta para que lo veas

Comment: @unknow si te deja meterlas pero te pide especificar las versiones porque esas dependencias estan administradas. Esto lo hacen los de spring desde hace algun tiempo debido a que sus librerias no siempre son compatibles, revisa la respuesta actualizada, y la proxima vez trata de que tus preguntas tengan todos los detalles relevantes